# Anchor/JumpTo in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use JSF + Primefaces 3.2.1.

There is an **p:datatable** on the page, in each row I have button "Edit". When I click that button, in the footer of the page renders a form for editing that row. Then I need to scroll down there to change values..

But I need the browser to scroll there automatically after clicking on "Edit" button like **Anchors** in basic HTML work.

I found this decision:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("pProvidersPriceAppointment.xhtml#anchor1");
```

It works, but with that my **update="@form"** not working.. So the form in the bottom not renders. It renders after refreshing page.

How can I do it with **p:commandButton** or **h:commandButton** ?)

**My button:**

```
<p:commandButton id="providerEdit" actionListener="#{providersPriceAppointment.setEditProvider(provider.id)}" icon="iconEdit" update="@form"/>
```

**Bean method:**

```
public void setEditProvider(int id) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < providersList.size(); i++) {
        ProvidersExt p = providersList.get(i);
        if (p.getId() == id) {
            providerForEdit = p;
            break;
        }
    }
    enableEdit = true;
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("pProvidersPriceAppointment.xhtml#anchor1");
}
```

**Form in the footer:**

```
<a name="anchor1"/>
<p:fieldset id="editFieldset" legend="blablabla" rendered="#{providersPriceAppointment.enableEdit}"/>
    ...
</p:fieldset>
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't something like this implemented in JSF or Primefaces yet. But since you have the jQuery Framework running in your application (Primefaces), you could use the jQuery Animate features.

To get a Hint on how to realize something like this, you could check out this answer:

[jQuery scroll to Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

For your application that would be somehow like that:

Add this to your `<head>` element:

```
function scrollToAnchor() {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#editFieldset").offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
```

And this would be the Button Part:

```
<p:commandButton id="providerEdit" 
    actionListener="# {providersPriceAppointment.setEditProvider(provider.id)}" 
    icon="iconEdit" onComplete="scrollToAnchor();" update="@form"/>
```

Comment: I use primefaces 3.2.1, it have jQuery v1.7.2, is **scrollTo** or **animate** supported in jQuery v1.7.2?

Comment: I did a quick google search and found documentation about .animate() in jQuery v1.7.2. I found a error in my JS example though. I used `$` instead of `jQuery`. I edited my answer. Please try it again :)

Comment: **Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: editFieldset** - thats in Google Chrome console. And after clicking button, form updates, editFieldset in footer appears, but browser not scrolling there and every button in my app loses its action, I mean clicking on any button causes no reaction.

Comment: Cool, I like this solution. Is working like a charme

Answer (score 3):

Use PrimeFaces RequestContext with `scrollTo` to target a component id:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml

```
public void save() { 
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

    ...
    //scroll to panel
    context.scrollTo("form:panel");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple decision that I found on PrimeFaces ShowCase:

```
<p:fieldset id="edit" legend="Here you can edit.." rendered="#{providersPriceAppointment.enableEdit}">
    <p:focus context="panel"/>  
</p:fieldset>
```

When this fieldset is rendered, browser simply jump to this place)
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/focus.xhtml

Hope, somebody will find this helpful (",)

Comment: URL for focus example is now: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/focus.xhtml